# I am not able to implement MouseUp, MouseDown and mouseMove Events in Xamarin Mobile applications

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

There is only valueChanged Event defined for Slider control, I need to develop mousedown,mouseup and Mousemove events. When a user clicks on the slider, on the view it should display "Mouse is up", "Mouse is down". But I can't able to develop that implementation.Any code help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: mouse events don't apply to touch interfaces

Comment: check MotionEvent class for mouse events

Answer (score 1):

There is no mouse in mobile, therefore there will not be any mouse events.

You have to look for GestureRecognizers, you can add TapGestureRecognizer, pan, pinch etc and so on to get events.